# PL/pgSQL issues when function used twice (caching problem?)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, functions, plpgsql, plan-cache

I am facing an absolutely weird problem that feels much like a Postgres bug than an algorithm problem.

I have this function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION sp_connect(mail character varying, passwd character varying, role character varying)
  RETURNS json LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE AS
$$
DECLARE
    user_info record;
BEGIN
  IF role = 'Role1' THEN
    SELECT u.id, r.name INTO user_info
    FROM users u
    INNER JOIN users_roles ur ON ur.user_id = u.id
    INNER JOIN roles r ON ur.role_id = r.id
    WHERE u.email = mail
      AND u.password = encode(digest(CONCAT(passwd, u.password_salt), 'sha512'), 'hex')
      AND r.name = 'Role1';
  ELSIF role = 'Role2' THEN
    SELECT h.id, 'Role1' AS name INTO user_info
    FROM history h
    WHERE h.email = mail
      AND h.password = encode(digest(CONCAT(passwd, h.password_salt), 'sha512'), 'hex');
  ELSE
    RAISE 'USER_NOT_FOUND';
  END IF;

  IF NOT FOUND THEN
      RAISE 'USER_NOT_FOUND';
  ELSE
      RETURN row_to_json(row) FROM (SELECT user_info.id AS id, user_info.name AS role) row;
  END IF;
END;
$$;
```

The problem I'm facing is when I use this function to log in with a Role1-user, then when I use it with a Role2-user, I get this error message:

```
type of parameter 7 (character varying) does not match that when preparing the plan (unknown)
```

Which is... well, I just don't understand where does it come from. If you wipe the database and change the login order (i.e. Role2 then Role1), this time, Role1 gets the error.

Strange issue, strange solutions... If I just use `ALTER FUNCTION sp_connect` but without modify anything inside the function, then magically, the two roles can login without any problem. I also tried this solution:

```
  IF NOT FOUND THEN
      RAISE 'USER_NOT_FOUND';
  ELSE
      IF role = 'Seeker'
      THEN
          RETURN row_to_json(row) FROM (SELECT user_info.id AS id, user_info.name AS role) row;
      ELSE
          RETURN row_to_json(row) FROM (SELECT user_info.id AS id, user_info.name AS role) row;
  END IF;
```

And by adding an `IF` and `ELSE` that is absolutely useless and use the same RETURN-clause, this does not trigger any error.

I know DBA StackExchange is not for developers but this kind of problem seems to be more like a caching problem or whatever. Can somebody can tell me if I am doing something wrong with PostgreSQL functions? Or where I may get help with this weird problem?

Comment: What happens if you make it volatile instead of stable?

Comment: At the beginning, it was volatile and same problem.

Comment: What makes you say that `DBA StackExchange is not for developers`? Of course it is, just for database related issues.

Comment: On the right of the "Ask Question" Page, there is a black stating `Is your question about database administration?`. That's why. (;

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Explanation:

You declare `user_info` as `record`. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-RECORDS)

> Record variables are similar to row-type variables, but they have no
> predefined structure. They take on the actual row structure of the row
> they are assigned during a `SELECT` or `FOR` command. **The substructure of
> a record variable can change each time it is assigned to**.

Bold emphasis mine.

You assign the record `user_info` and then derive a row type (actually called `row` in your code) from it in the `RETURN` statement. This is all fine and dandy, until you assign columns of *different* data types to the record in the next call within the same session. This is incompatible with the cached query plan of the prepared statement and raises an exception.

PL/pgSQL treats SQL statements in the function body as ***prepared statements***. After some initial runs, the query plan can be cached for the duration of the session

Altering any involved object (including the function itself) deallocates query plans of depending prepared statements. This explains why the next invocation after `ALTER FUNCTION` always worked. More explanation:

- [Function Performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8119/function-performance/8189#8189)

#### Solution

There are various ways around this. You found some yourself already. Just avoid feeding parameters of different data type to the same (prepared) statement

The simple solution would be to **cast to the same data type**. You didn't provide table definitions, I assume `users.id` and `history.id` are `integer` and match just fine. Judging from the error message I assume `roles.name` is `varchar`, so I cast the string literal `'Role1'` to `varchar` as well and everything should work. <sub>(You might actually mean `'Role2'`, but that's orthogonal to the problem.)</sub>

An untyped string literal is coerced to a matching data type in some types of SQL statements where a data type can be derived from the context. But that's not the case here. Without explicit cast the string literal is type `unknown`, which is *not* the same as `varchar` (or `text`). This also shows in your error message.

```
CREATE FUNCTION sp_connect(mail varchar, passwd varchar, role varchar)
  RETURNS json
  LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE AS
$func$
DECLARE
   user_info record;
BEGIN
   IF role = 'Role1' THEN
      SELECT u.id, r.name INTO user_info
      FROM   users u
      JOIN   users_roles ur ON ur.user_id = u.id
      JOIN   roles r ON ur.role_id = r.id
      WHERE  u.email = mail
      AND    u.password = encode(digest(concat(passwd, u.password_salt), 'sha512'), 'hex')
      AND    r.name = 'Role1';

      RAISE NOTICE 'Role1: user_info.big_id: %; user_info.name: %', pg_typeof(user_info.big_id), pg_typeof(user_info.name);  -- see data types
   ELSIF role = 'Role2' THEN
      SELECT h.id, 'Role1'::varchar AS name INTO user_info  -- Cast! And did you mean 'Role2'?
      FROM   history h
      WHERE  h.email = mail
      AND    h.password = encode(digest(CONCAT(passwd, h.password_salt), 'sha512'), 'hex');

      RAISE NOTICE 'Role2: user_info.big_id: %; user_info.name: %', pg_typeof(user_info.big_id), pg_typeof(user_info.name);  -- see data types
   END IF;

  IF NOT FOUND THEN
      RAISE 'USER_NOT_FOUND';
  ELSE
      RETURN row_to_json(row) FROM (SELECT user_info.id AS id, user_info.name AS role) row;
  END IF;
END
$func$;
```

The function can be `STABLE`, that's the correct volatility.

I also added `RAISE NOTICE` statements to show data types, which should help you debug. Note that the plan for the `RAISE` statement itself is cached as well, so a single `RAISE` after `END IF` would be subject to the same problem.

Comment: That's an amazing answer ! Thank you very much Erwin, I wouldn't be able to understand all the mechanics under the hood without this incredible explanation. Thank you very much again !

Comment: I had a similar problem where I passed a RECORD type to a function. I was getting this error from a function call (`to_jsonb`) within the function. When I changed the function declaration to use ANYELEMENT instead of RECORD (and then cast to record when calling `to_jsonb`), I stopped getting the query plan error.