# Wildcard search using parameters in function with dynamic SQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, sql-injection

What is the proper way to implement a wildcard search in PostgreSQL when using a parameter in a function that uses dynamic SQL?

As a starting point, here is an example from Erwin Brandstetter answering a different question on Stackoverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12047277/538962

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION report_get_countries_new (starts_with text
                                                   , ends_with   text = NULL)
RETURNS SETOF lookups.countries AS
$func$
DECLARE
   sql text := 'SELECT * FROM lookups.countries WHERE country_name >= $1';
BEGIN
   IF ends_with IS NOT NULL THEN
      sql := sql || ' AND country_name <= $2';
   END IF;

   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE sql
   USING starts_with, ends_with;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Let's suppose for `country_name` you wanted to do a leading and trailing wildcard search.

E.g., without using a parameter,  `AND country_name LIKE '%ic%'`.

What is the best way to implement the wildcard search be in this scenario with respect to negating SQL injection risk?
I am currently using PostgreSQL 9.5.1.

Answer (score 9):

> Let's suppose for `country_name` you wanted to do a leading and trailing wildcard search.

You don't need dynamic SQL for this. Just:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION report_get_countries_new (_pattern text)
  RETURNS SETOF lookups.countries
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
   SELECT *
   FROM   lookups.countries
   WHERE  country_name LIKE '%' || _pattern || '%'
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM report_get_countries_new ('ic');  -- no wildcards!
```

This negates SQL-injection risk *completely*, which comes with dynamic SQL.

The caller can still include wildcards at will (unless you process the parameter to filter wildcards), but there is a hardcoded leading wildcard and also a trailing one (unless the parameter ends with `\` removing the special meaning from the trailing `%`).

Even if you work with dynamic SQL and `EXECUTE` in PL/pgSQL, there is no risk for SQL injection as long as you pass values as *values* with the `USING` clause:

Related:

- [SQL injection in Postgres functions vs prepared queries](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49699/sql-injection-in-postgres-functions-vs-prepared-queries)
- [Function Performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8119/postgresql-stored-procedure-performance/8189#8189)
- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10711349/939860)

Comment: Thanks. For other reasons, I have to use dynamic sql. So if I understand you correctly, it would be ok to add wildcards to the parameter outside of the function and thereby call, `SELECT * FROM report_get_countries_new ('%ic%');`

Comment: @mg1075: There is no risk for SQL injection as long as you don't convert user input to SQL code (or identifiers). Passing values as *values* with the `USING` clause is 100% safe. *Concatenating* user input into the query string needs more attention and should be avoided for *values*.

Comment: Sorry, I might be getting tripped up by semantics. What if inside the function, **prior** to passing `starts_with` to the `USING` clause, I had a stand-alone clause saying `starts_with = '%' || starts_with || '%'`. This would be ok, since the value is passed as a *value* to the `USING` clause?

Comment: @mg1075: Concatenating strings is not crossing the value / code border and safe. *Executing* concatenated strings that include user input can be a problem - but not as long as you pass them as *value*. I added another link that should help to clarify.