# Split cases in WHERE clause based on boolean variable

Tags: postgresql, query, case

I have to split a `WHERE` clause based on a boolean variable:

If `ShowZeroVariable` is `true`, I only what to show rows value 0 in a certain integer column.
If `false` I want to show all that are greater than 0.

Something like this:

```
select IntField from Table 
where  
IntField 
case 
when ShowZeroVariable  = 'true' then = '0'
else <= '0'
end
```

I can only get it to kind of work by casting to text 
*(But this doesn't filter out the zero values when false)*:

```
select IntField from Table 
where  
IntField::text like
case 
when ShowZeroVariable  = 'true' then '0'
else '%'
end
```

Can't seem to get a `WHERE` clause `CASE` statement to work with operators `<` / `=` / `>`.

Answer (score 2):

`CASE` probably isn't the right tool here. But you can use a Boolean expression.

```
...
WHERE showzerovariable
      AND intfield = 0
       OR NOT showzerovariable
          AND intfield > 0
...
```

Comment: Yes that is so obvious now; worked like a charm.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

[`CASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) isn't too bad either:

```
...
WHERE CASE showzerovariable
         WHEN true  THEN int_column = 0
         WHEN false THEN int_column > 0
      END
```

Simpler if the variable is defined `NOT NULL`:

```
...
WHERE CASE WHEN showzerovariable THEN int_column = 0 ELSE int_column > 0 END
```

**But** if your query can benefit from indexes this is not working nicely with prepared statements (`showzerovariable` being the variable input). (If more than a few percent of all rows meet each condition, indexes are useless.) And PL/pgSQL likes to treat queries as prepared statements - if some preconditions are met. See:

- [Function Performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8119/function-performance/8189#8189)

**If** indexes are useful for at least one sub-case **and** you are indeed using PL/pgSQL, consider splitting cases to optimize performance. Like:

```
IF showzerovariable THEN
   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT ...
   WHERE  int_column = 0;
ELSE
   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT ...
   WHERE  int_column > 0;
END IF;
```