# How to create a postgres function that returns a value

Tags: postgresql, insert, functions

I am trying to move some of my web app logic into postgres functions. But I am hitting some errors while creating a very basic insert function.

This is the function that I am trying to create;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_user(IN email EMAIL, password TEXT, thumb TEXT)
RETURNS text AS 
$BODY$
BEGIN
   insert into users (unqid, thumb, email, password) 
   values (gen_random_uuid(), thumb, email, password)
   returning unqid ;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
  VOLATILE
```

I am trying to get the function to return the uuid of the item if the insert is successful.
And I am calling it like this;

```
select * from create_user('newuser@mail.com', 'passpopcorn', 'thumbelinaurl');
```

Getting this error;

```
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: query has no destination for result data
  Where: PL/pgSQL function create_user(email,text,text) line 3 at SQL statement
```

From my googling it sounds like this error comes up when you don't have a return statement in the query. But in my Insert query, I do have a returning statement.

Extra question; for simple insert statements (like this one here, or one with a couple of select followed by an insert), would functions be a better bet or procedures?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: query has no destination for result data

`insert ... returning ...` produces a result set that contains columns referenced in the `returning` clause. In a PL/pgSQL block that result set must be dealt with somehow. You have three options:

- An intermediate variable

  ```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_user(IN email EMAIL, password TEXT, thumb TEXT)
    RETURNS VARCHAR(40) AS 
    $BODY$
    DECLARE id VARCHAR(40);
    BEGIN
       insert into users (unqid, thumb, email, password) 
       values (gen_random_uuid(), thumb, email, password)
       returning unqid INTO id;
       RETURN id;
    END;
    $BODY$
      LANGUAGE plpgsql
      VOLATILE
  ```
- `return query`, which avoids an extra variable

  ```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_user(IN email EMAIL, password TEXT, thumb TEXT)
    RETURNS TABLE (id VARCHAR(40)) AS 
    $BODY$
    BEGIN
       RETURN QUERY 
       insert into users (unqid, thumb, email, password) 
       values (gen_random_uuid(), thumb, email, password)
       returning unqid;
    END;
    $BODY$
      LANGUAGE plpgsql
      VOLATILE
  ```
- A simple SQL function, which I would prefer in your case as you don't need any PL/pgSQL functionality as it stands

  ```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_user(IN email EMAIL, password TEXT, thumb TEXT)
    RETURNS TABLE (id VARCHAR(40)) AS 
    $BODY$
       insert into users (unqid, thumb, email, password) 
       values (gen_random_uuid(), thumb, email, password)
       returning unqid;
    $BODY$
      LANGUAGE SQL
  ```

Comment: is there any inherent benefit of using SQL functions over pl/pgsql ones?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8119/function-performance

Answer (score 3):

A function basically replaces a fixed values when used as you do

so your code would look like

> ```
> CREATE TABLE users (unqid varchar(64), thumb TEXT, email TEXT, password TEXT)
> ```

> ```
> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_user(IN email TEXT, password TEXT, thumb TEXT)
> RETURNS text AS 
> $BODY$
> DECLARE _unqid varchar(64);
> BEGIN
>    
>  _unqid = gen_random_uuid();
>    insert into users (unqid, thumb, email, password) 
>    values (_unqid, thumb, email, password);
>    RETURN  _unqid ;
> END;
> $BODY$
>   LANGUAGE plpgsql
>   VOLATILE
> ```

> ```
> select create_user('newuser@mail.com', 'passpopcorn', 'thumbelinaurl')
> ```
>
> ```
> | create_user                          |
> | :----------------------------------- |
> | 759f4da9-bc17-4349-be4c-34e9b76fb78b |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM users
> ```
>
> ```
> unqid                                | thumb         | email            | password   
> :----------------------------------- | :------------ | :--------------- | :----------
> 759f4da9-bc17-4349-be4c-34e9b76fb78b | thumbelinaurl | newuser@mail.com | passpopcorn
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=42da830facf261575601429cb99ea099)*