# Executing try catch block in mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql-5.5, stored-procedures

In my mysql stored procedure I want try catch block but it gives error in my mysql stored procedure .

I want my select query to be in try block 
and if it executes correctly I want other query to execute.

code statement for mysql

```
BEGIN
 begin try 
     select userId into user from users ;
 end try
 begin catch 
    select 1;
 end catch 
 begin finally
   select postId from photo where userId=user;
 end finally 
END
```

but it gives error is there any try catch block for mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're mixing up Java (other language?) with MySQL's stored procedure language. Look [here](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/Error-Handling/) and [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5746/equivalent-functions-in-mysql-that-exist-in-sql-server). Check out [this](http://guyharrison.squarespace.com/blog/2013/7/5/using-get-diagnostics-in-mysql-56.html) by Guy Harrison, the guy who wrote this [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596100892).

Comment: adding links in answers is dangerous as links might go away.